# Pandas NaT explicit instantiation and assertion using pd.isna

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working with datetimes and for a set of reasons I need to handle `NaT` values. This is no big deal. But I just bumped into a curious situation while implementing unit tests:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp.now(), None])
0   2022-02-04 08:46:35.458897
1                          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]

type(s[1])
pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType

pd.isna(s[1])
True

pd.isna(type(s[1])())  # unexpected
False

type(s[1])()
NaT
```

I wonder why `unexpected` above was observed and **that is my question**.

Context: discovered this when trying to explicitly instantiate a `NaT` for testing purposes (eg `pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType()`). Solution: using exactly `s[1]` as from above.

Comment: side note, works as expected if coerced to numpy type: `pd.isna(type(s[1])().asm8)` => `True`

Comment: @MrFuppes that's a start. Thanks. I might find time and motivation to look into the Cython code and try to understand this.